# "Enthusiastic" badge completed - "Fanatic" badge reset?

Tags: discussion, badges

So I got the "Enthusiastic" badge for visiting 30 consecutive days. However, my progress to the "Fanatic" badge is **0**. Shouldn't it be **30**? I didn't skip a day yet. Is this a bug or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: Click the "[visited 124 days](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5889375/abappletic?tab=profile)" link in your profile; looks like you missed the 29th, which would cause the counter to reset.

Comment: @Shog9 but I got the "Enthusiastic" badge, which means I didn't miss it

Comment: You got "Enthusiast" on the 28th

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the Fanatic badge to you need to visit on 100 consecutive days. If these are your first 100 days on the site then you will have already earned the Enthusiastic badge at 30 days.

However, if you miss a day between the 31st and 100th day the counter is reset completely so you start again with 0 consecutive days. You don't start from 30.

You missed days on the 29th September and before that the 29th August.