# Fanatic Badge counter reset

Tags: discussion, support

EDIT: Based on comments, I'd like to refine my question. What is the criteria for the Fanatic Badge? Why is this criteria not public? Based on community observed assumptions based on gaining the badge, what constitutes as "Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days"?

### The Problem I Encountered

I'm not sure where to bring this up but maybe Meta can shed some light on what's happened.

I, like many others, have been working towards getting the Fanatic badge on SO. I check the site multiple times a day (on my phone, ipad, computer) to see what new questions pop up and such. I've been working a lot recently, so my activity has fallen off sharply, but I do still check into the site multiple times every day.

A couple days ago before I went to sleep, I checked my Fanatic progress and it said I was at 95/100. The next day at around 5pm (~17 hours after last login) I checked it again and it said I was at 1/100.

Did this happen because I haven't been actively posting? I had gone multiple days prior to this without activity, but still browsing questions and the counter hadn't reset, so why would it reset this time? I'm afraid I might be confused with how this badge works.. It's disappointing that I was so close only to have the counter reset for a reason that eludes me.

Comment: Up for two minutes, down-voted with no explanation. What has become of Meta.....

Comment: Two things: 1) Pretty sure this is a duplicate, for asking why it reset at least. 2) The "login tracker" is already a thing- Click the "visited x days, y consecutive" line in your profile to see it.

Comment: If this is not a feature-request, it is a duplicate of [Second time that Stack Overflow's daily visits counter resets for “fanatic” badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298530/215552). Or [“Enthusiastic” badge completed - “Fanatic” badge reset?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335626/215552).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I had already read both of those and don't feel they apply? I browse through questions every day and read answers. By not being active, I meant I'm not making questions/answer posts or comments. I'm still browsing through questions and answers though. In that first one you linked, it does say that this _should_ be enough. I guess my question is, is that not enough? Do I need to make a comment at the very least every single day for 100 days?

Comment: @Kendra Thanks, I removed all of that from my question. I didn't know that was a button.

Comment: @Tyeler Did you really read the answers thoroughly? Because ChrisF's answer states *"The exact criteria aren't public though, so even if I knew I couldn't tell you."*, which tells you what you need to know.

Comment: To be fair, you have to hover over the line to realize it's clickable. They don't exactly make it obvious, so kinda easy to miss.

Comment: @Tyeler you mention 5pm, but not what time zone.  You are aware that the time is based on the UTC day and not a 24 hour cycle from your last login

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, that's why I posted the interval between the last two logins being ~17 hours. It's saying that I didn't log in on Sunday, but I did during my lunch at noon, and again at night. I'm not even concerned with the time zone because I browse questions and such at less than 24 hour intervals.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I guess that would be my question. Why isn't the criteria for that badge public, and if based on what we know as a community about that badge, how did I not meet the observed/assumed criteria?

Comment: @Tyeler The best I can find to sort of start figuring out why your visits Sunday didn't count is [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485) by Jeff Atwood. It looks like if you just "browse" the questions list it doesn't count. Did you actually visit any questions that day, or just browsed the list? (You might have to check your comp's history for those times to sort that out.) If you did, I have no idea then.

Comment: @Kendra I did click on questions. I usually click on questions with down-votes to see if there's anything I can do to improve the question to hopefully help the user gain a more positive response from the community. I didn't make any edits but I do remember the questions that I visited on Sunday. I could link them for whatever that may be worth. I don't know if Admins can see exactly which users view a question, but if they can it should check out.

Comment: Then my only assumption can be just viewing a question does not count, either. I think team members can check logs to give you more info, but I don't know if they will.

Comment: Well.. that's a shame. The whole thing is weird because I didn't do anything different on Sunday that I hadn't been doing every other day. Obviously I did do something different but I don't know what it would be. Guess I'll do a review queue each day for the next 98 days and see how that goes. _Thank you everyone for your help and fast responses!_

Comment: By way of experiment I did visit the site for 1,000 consecutive days (and then some). Alas, I found out the hard way there is no gold Fanatic badge.